# How can I place a button in the Columnheader of CheckboxTableviewer ? And when I click that button I want all rows to be selected

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer

How can I place a button in the `Columnheader` of `CheckboxTableviewer` ?
 And when I click that button I want all rows to be selected. My table has 10 columns,

1. I want a button in the columnheader,
2. when I click that button I want all the rows of the table to be selected.

This is my table

```
    final CheckboxTableViewer dataTable = CheckboxTableViewer.newCheckList(TableComposite2, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL   
                | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER |SWT.DM_FILL_BACKGROUND|SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        dataTable .getTable().setHeaderVisible(true);
        dataTable .getTable().setLinesVisible(true);
        dataTable .setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());


    //Action Check box
        TableColumn columnCHead=new TableColumn(dataTable .getTable(),SWT.NONE);
        columnCHead.setText("Delete");

        columnCHead.setWidth(50);
        // setting column input
        TableViewerColumn columnC=new TableViewerColumn(dataTable ,columnCHead);
        columnC.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider()
        {
            public String getText(Object Element)
            {

                return null;
            }
        });

        TableColumn columnFS1Head=new TableColumn(dataTable .getTable(),SWT.NONE);
        columnFS1Head.setText("SOURCE DIRECTORY");
        columnFS1Head.setWidth(300);

        TableViewerColumn columnFS1=new TableViewerColumn(dataTable ,columnFS1Head);
        columnFS1.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider()
        {
            public String getText(Object Element)
            {
                AgedFileMaster a=(AgedFileMaster)Element;
                return a.getDIRECTORY_PATH();
            }
```

In the first column, I want that button instead of text "delete". Anyone please help. I am beginner to SWT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TableColumn` already behaves like a button, just use `addSelectionListener` to listen for the button being pressed. You can't easily add controls to the column header.

To select everything call

```
Object [] elements = get all the elements in your data model

dataTable.setSelecton(new StructuredSelection(elements));
```

Comment: " get all the elements in your data model" means what exactly? can u please give the sample code?

Comment: The data model is the array or list you give to the `setInput` method.